# Merge [django-south] with [south]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I have found that for the django database migration tool South there are two tags:

[south](/questions/tagged/south) x 216 and [django-south](/questions/tagged/django-south) x 201

Both are related to the same topic. I am not familiar with the procedure, but I think it makes sense to either merge them or create a synonym.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but I [requested this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118974/synonymize-south-and-django-south) several months ago

Comment: I did not see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makes sense to me. I set up a synonym from [south](/questions/tagged/south) to [django-south](/questions/tagged/django-south) and merged them as well.